# Unity (C#) Transport API not sending data with Send() function

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine

I've got a project with a client and a server that needs to receive info from a client. Using the Transport Layer here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetUsingTransport.html, I have created a client and a server script that I have added to this post.

I am able to connect to the port that my server creates, but something is happening to where the message is getting lost when trying to use the Send() and Receive() functions. No DataEvent is getting through, and I'm not sure what the issue could be at this point. The documentation is pretty sparse on how this works, so any help would be appreciated. I also looked on this site, but this does not seem to be a common problem.

Basically there are three main functions that handle this: the Connect() function executes in the client to connect to the server's open socket; the SendSocketMessage() is executed on Update() in the client; and the ReceiveSocketMessage() is executed on Update() in the server.

```
public void Connect()
{
    byte error;
    connectionId = NetworkTransport.Connect(socketID, receiverIP,    socketPort, 0, out error);
    Debug.Log ("Connected to server. ConnectionId: " + connectionId);
    Debug.Log ("Connected on Socket: " + socketID);

}
```

[ReceiveSocketMessage()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8tuR.png)

```
public void SendSocketMessage() {
    byte error;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(stream, "HelloServer");

    int bufferSize = 1024;

    NetworkTransport.Send(socketID, connectionId, myReliableChannelId, buffer, bufferSize, out error);
}
```

In addition, if there is an easier (easy to learn and apply quickly) way to send and receive messages for Unity, I am all ears. Thanks!

How can I get Unity to start talking across this transport?